# How to display "All Selected" when parameter (Select All) is selected in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Using SSRS 2008 r2...I have a report with a single-value parameter and three multi-value parameters, Class1, Name2 and Name3. I'm hoping for an explanation to one thing that I'm seeing and information on a second thing.

One, on the image, Class1 and Name2 both have the (Select All) parameter selected but Class1 is displaying the concatenated parameter variable list whereas Name2 is showing Null. Why is that? If anything, how can I get Class1 to be similar to Name2 and show Null?

[image: Report Parameters]

But my desired wish is to have Class1, Name2 and Name3 display the text"All Selected" when the parameter (Select All) is chosen. How can this be achieved?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The datasets referred by Class1, Name2 and Name3 should contain the value **All Selected**.

To do that you need to add the below codes to the existing datasets:

```
UNION
SELECT 'ALL SELECTED' as DefaultValue
```

Then put the default value of all your required parameters to "All Selected".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a dataset as a source for your multi-select parameter:

"DataSet2" is my source for the multi-select parameter "pmPlant".  I check if the number of selected items in your mutli-select parameter match the number of items in your source dataset.  If it is, then display your desired text ("All Plants" in this case), if not then then use the "Join" function to combine the selections as a ";" separated list.

```
=iif(Parameters!pmPlant.Count = CountRows( "DataSet2",  ),"All Plants", Join(Parameters!pmPlant.Label,"; "))
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

`=IIF(Parameters!ParameterName.Count = COUNT(1, "Dataset Name"), "All", Parameters!ParameterName)`